# MongoEngine version for MongoDB 3.2.20

Tags: python, pymongo, mongoengine

Our MongoDB version is to be upgraded to 3.2 from 3.0. [This matrix](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#python-driver-compatibility) shows we need PyMongo version to be 3.2 for working with mongodb 3.2. We will be upgrading PyMongo to 3.2. But not sure which MongoEngine version to move to. [MongoEngine site](https://pypi.org/project/mongoengine/#description) says 3.2+  is not supported yet.

Any inputs on which MongoEngine version to move to?

Our current versions:
MongoDB: 3.0
PyMongo: 2.8.1
MongoEngine: 0.8.7

Versions to upgrade to:
MongoDB: 3.2.20
PyMongo: 3.2
MongoEngine: Not sure

Comment: Go ahead to use the latest version for MongoEngine. Test to know if there are any issues with it. For the most parts, you should be fine and you can't know this until you try.

Comment: Thanks for the response @OluwafemiSule. Moving from 0.8.7 to 0.15 is a big gap. Which intermediate version of mongoengine would you suggest that supports mongoDB v3.2 just like the latest version does?